# How to normalize irregular data values

Tags: shell-script, numeric-data

From a PHP table I get the values graphically represented. However some of the data received is 'damaged' or incorrect thus yielding a non-sensible graphical representation.

The hours (y-axis) is accumulated hours, just like the odometer of a car, except for hours and the x-axis is the corresponding dates. Logically the hours of tomorrow will be greater or equal to hours of today, this  should be either a flat line or increasing. But alas this is the output:

[image]

I would like to normalize this data so it has a somewhat more 'correct' representation looking something like:

[image]

I have been reading up some information about normalizing data ([Database normalization process](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/database_normalization_process.html), [Normalising a data set with irregular intervals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422905/normalising-a-data-set-with-irregular-intervals-in-python), [Data Normalization and Standardization](http://www.benetzkorn.com/2011/11/data-normalization-and-standardization/)) but I can't seem get a start on *how to actually normalize the data*. I'm either really having a blonde moment, or I just don't get it.

**Q:** How can I normalize this data set with Bash - what would be the steps involved - I would be grateful for a pseudo code or a description on the involved steps.

Comment: Fixated upon your "should be" line, can you tell us why you wouldn't just wish to compute a line between your maximum and minimum coordinate pairs?  (ymax - ymin) = m*(xmax - xmin) ?  Tell us how this is wrong, and then the next (more wise) person will give you a better reply

Comment: Bash isn't useful for this job except to glue tools together. Look into [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), it's designed for statistics.

Comment: @Theophrastus: I think the situation is that the OP has a real-world function that is monotonically increasing (because it is a cumulative function), with a flawed sampling mechanism.  Any value that is lower than the maximum of the preceding values is presumed to be “damaged”/incorrect — but, conversely, all others are presumed to be accurate.  And he wants to cover spans where the data are damaged by interpolating linearly between the valid points at the end of the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Your illustration doesn’t really seem to match your words. 
If you mean what you *say* (and if I’m understanding your words correctly),
and assuming you have a list of “Y” values
(i.e., the numbers of hours, ranging between 0 and 2400)
that you want to normalize, you can do what you want with this `awk` code:

```
awk '
    NR==1 { prev_good = $1 }
    {
        data = $1
        if (data < prev_good) {
                count++
                next
        }
        if (count > 0) {
                count++
                for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                        print prev_good + (data-prev_good) * i / count
                }
                count = 0
        }
        print data
        prev_good = data
}'
```

It assumes that the first data point is valid (`NR==1 { prev_good = $1 }`). 
Thereafter,
if a data point is less than the previous good value (`prev_good`,
which is the largest value seen so far), treat it as invalid:
skip it (`next`) and count the points that you’ve skipped. 
When you get a good value, test `count` — if it’s positive,
that means we have skipped some data, so generate that many data values,
linearly interpolating between the last good value and the current value. 
Then print the new valid value.

If your input contains “X” and “Y” (date and hours),
this becomes a bit more complicated —
especially if the “X” intervals are not uniform.

You could do this as a pure shell script, but that would be silly. 
`awk`, however, seems to be a good tool for the job.